# Rails Amazon S3 direct upload with JQuery File Uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload, pre-signed-url

I have spent days now trying to make this work. I am getting this error

> OPTIONS https://bucketname.s3.oregon.amazonaws.com/ net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED

I am using `Version 43.0.2357.130 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)`

Gemfile:

```
gem "jquery-fileupload-rails"
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

application.js (after jquery):

```
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
```

application.css:

```
 *= require jquery.fileupload
 *= require jquery.fileupload-ui
```

I have a model called uploads that I have generated scaffolds for like this:

```
rails generate scaffold Upload upload_url:string
```

uploads_controller.rb:

```
def new
  @s3_direct_post = Aws::S3::PresignedPost.new(Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']), 
                                                "Oregon", ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET'], {
                                                key: '/uploads/object/test.test',
                                                content_length_range: 0..999999999,
                                                acl: 'public-read',
                                                success_action_status: "201",
                                              })
  @upload = Upload.new
end
```

_form.html.erb (for uploads):

```
<%= form_for(@upload, html: { class: "directUpload" }) do |f| %>
......
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :upload_url %><br>
  <%= f.file_field :upload_url %>
</div>
......
<%= content_tag "div", id: "upload_data", data: {url: @s3_direct_post.url, form_data: @s3_direct_post.fields } do %>
<% end %>
```

application.js (in the end):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
      $('.directUpload').find("input:file").each(function(i, elem) {
        var fileInput    = $(elem);
        var form         = $(fileInput.parents('form:first'));
        var submitButton = form.find('input[type="submit"]');
        var progressBar  = $("<div class='bar'></div>");
        var barContainer = $("<div class='progress'></div>").append(progressBar);
        fileInput.after(barContainer);
        fileInput.fileupload({
          fileInput:       fileInput,
          url:             $('#upload_data').data('url'),
          type:            'POST',
          autoUpload:       true,
          formData:         $('#upload_data').data('form-data'),
          paramName:        'file', // S3 does not like nested name fields i.e. name="user[avatar_url]"
          dataType:         'XML',  // S3 returns XML if success_action_status is set to 201
          replaceFileInput: false,
          progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            progressBar.css('width', progress + '%')
          },
          start: function (e) {
            submitButton.prop('disabled', true);

            progressBar.
              css('background', 'green').
              css('display', 'block').
              css('width', '0%').
              text("Loading...");
          },
          done: function(e, data) {
            submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
            progressBar.text("Uploading done");

            // extract key and generate URL from response
            var key   = $(data.jqXHR.responseXML).find("Key").text();

            // create hidden field
            var input = $("<input />", { type:'hidden', name: fileInput.attr('name'), value: url })
            form.append(input);
          },
          fail: function(e, data) {
            submitButton.prop('disabled', false);

            progressBar.
              css("background", "red").
              text("Failed");
          }
        });
      });
    });
    });
```

Seriously What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Thanks a lot to [felixbuenemann a collaborator in jquery-fileupload-rails](https://github.com/felixbuenemann)

[image]

Although that is what I see in the properties (it says Region: Oregon), I have to use "us-west-2" according to this [Amazon region documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region)

uploads_controller.rb is now:

```
def new
  @s3_direct_post = Aws::S3::PresignedPost.new(Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']), 
                                                "us-west-2", ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET'], {
                                                key: '/uploads/object/test.test',
                                                content_length_range: 0..999999999,
                                                acl: 'public-read',
                                                success_action_status: "201",
                                              })
  @upload = Upload.new
end
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have misconfigured your bucket name / route. The error comes from Amazon, warning you there is no DNS route to https://bucketname.s3.oregon.amazonaws.com/.

It seems to me you need to set the actual bucketname to your *bucket name*, and also drop *oregon* from the url. Given that your bucket is named *aymansalah*, the url will be: https://aymansalah.s3.amazonaws.com/

Review `Aws::Credentials` documentation and check your environment variables to achieve that URL.